# How to properly extend user model in Django

Tags: python, django, one-to-one, django-users, abstractuser

I am working on a Django employee management system, I want the employee bio data on the same table as the user object used for registration and login

I tried adding the user model as a OnetoOneField on the employee table, but I don’t like having to register the user and then fill the employee form separately.

I want the users to be able to create their bio data while creating an account

Comment: Have you tried to google it? First hit: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Answer (score 1):

you can inherit AbstractBaseUser model and override it(add additionally fields in it) and you can do what exactly you want i.e

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ---> rest of fields <------
```

Answer (score 0):

database design may always vary depending on people. In such a case, I will inherit abstractbaseuser and keep everything in that table.